# How to structure a multi module project with interfaces in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, module, intellij-idea, gradle, modularity

I'm trying to structure my application (built with Gradle and developed in IntelliJ, this seems pretty crucial here) in a modular way (using Guice for modules and DI). The thing is I would like modules to communicate only via interfaces, so ideally I'd like to achieve this kind of structure:

```
+-- project
   +-- module1
      +-- src
         +-- iface
         +-- impl
         +-- test
      +-- build.gradle
   ..
   +-- moduleX
      +-- src
         +-- iface
         +-- impl
         +-- test
      +-- build.gradle
```

And in `build.gradle` I'd like to just include `project('moduleX', configuration : 'iface')` or something similar.

In Gradle I can do it with sourceSets etc., that's all cool! But the problem is that IntelliJ doesn't recognize it since I do it in gradle scripts! For IntelliJ it's still just a single module.

This is pretty strange since even maven supported a similar project structure (if I remember correctly). Does this mean that there is some other way to achieve what I want? And that IntelliJ expects me to use that approach or does it just want me to separate iface and the rest as separate modules (a thing I want to avoid, I don't want too many modules in my projects since it slows down the dev environment)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using source sets, you'd typically structure this as a multi-project build, which would be mapped to a multi-module project in IntelliJ, and a workspace with multiple projects in Eclipse. To learn more about multi-project builds, check out the corresponding chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: but doesn't that mean that I basically need 2 project per each module? 1 for the API, 1 for the implementation. That might get a bit hectic with a lot of modules. Actually we already are using the multiproject build but with different level of granularity. I'd still prefer gradle to support projects with iface/impl/test folders but oh well, guess I'll go with the multiproject approach ;-)

Comment: You don't need to have separate projects for `iface`/`impl`/`test`. By default, IntelliJ will pick up all source directories for the `main` and `test` source sets. See the [DSL reference](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html) for how to declare additional source dirs.